# "Recently my imagination works badly" is the sentence correct or not?

Tags: present-perfect, adverbs, past-simple, present-simple

I want to know what time tense should I use in this sentence? I know that an adverb "Recently" is allowed to use only with the present/past perfect tenses. So I can't use it with the present simple, can I? The same question about an adverb "already".
Is it correct "I already finished" or is it necessary to use the "I've already finished" instead of that?

Comment: Just a side note, already is usually used in present simple tense in sentences like "It's already under way". Not sure about the other instances.

Comment: Thank  you  for the answer

Comment: Please look at existing questions and answers. Here is one about [**already**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/131107/27840) and one about [**recently**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/54540/27840).

Answer (score 1):

"Recently, my imagination has been working badly" seems to be more appropriate, for the already mentioned reason that it is generally used with present/past perfect tenses.

As for the second question, "I've already finished" sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!